# Open source webapp to collaboratively decide a date/time across multiple timezones (alternative to Doodle)

Tags: open-source, web-apps, hosted, scheduling

I have to schedule a hackathon with Open Source developers. We want to use only Open Source solutions.

Constraints:

- we don't want to host the application by ourselves → it has to be an existing website
- we don't want to force/to be forced to give our email addresses → it has to be usable without inscription
- we can make mistakes → polls and answers has to be editable
- if possible, we are looking for something also usable to do little polls (not only date polls)

Is there an Open Source alternative to Doodle?

Comment: It might halp a little if you told us what Doodle is/does ...

Comment: But you could try   http://alternativeto.net/software/doodle/

Comment: @Mawg: i guess you meant https://alternativeto.net/software/doodle/?license=opensource

Comment: Oh, thank you! I didn't know this website and didn't find it doing my research :D @Mawg ok, the next time I'll be more precise about the application, thank you for your help.

Comment: by the way: if you are running a ownCloud/Nextcloud-instance there is also a [Polls-app](https://github.com/v1r0x/polls) available. ;-)

Comment: maybe there is also something useful: https://github.com/Kickball/awesome-selfhosted#polls-and-events

Comment: If it’s running on someone’s server, you can never be sure that the software is really open source. Even if they use an open source tool, they might have made proprietary modifications to it (unless they use a license like the AGPL, installing it on a server is not distribution, so possible copyleft terms don’t apply).

Answer (score 3):

**Dudle** fulfills all the requested points and has proven useful in its first usage.

Demo: https://dudle.inf.tu-dresden.de/?lang=en

License: AGPL Version 3

Source code: https://github.com/kellerben/dudle/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Rallly** is a free collaborative scheduling service.
Limitation: It only allows voting on a date, not on a time.
Runnable with docker-compose.

Source code: https://github.com/lukevella/Rallly

Demo: https://rallly.co

MIT License

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Framadate**: Online service for planning an appointment or make a decision quickly and easily: Make a poll, Define dates or subjects to choose, Send the poll link to your friends or colleagues, Discuss and make a decision.
Written in PHP.

Source code: https://framagit.org/framasoft/framadate

Demo: https://framadate.org/

License: [CeCILL-B](https://framagit.org/framasoft/framadate/framadate/-/blob/develop/LICENSE.en.txt) (compatible with GPL)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Croodle** seems to have the option to vote not only on dates but also on times.
Written in PHP.
Warning: I have not tested it, and there is no demo server.

Source code: https://github.com/jelhan/croodle

License: MIT